# ASCII Extended in C# string

Tags: c#, ascii

How do I make a string in C# to accept non printable ASCII extended characters like • , cause when I try to put • in a string it just give a blank space or null.

Comment: You need to give some more context here: are you making a string literal, reading the string from console, or getting it through a UI control?

Comment: Can you give example of your code? To clarify question?

Comment: Be sure to read this article by Joel Spolsky if you haven't already: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Did you edit this? Because I answered but then it seemed different :/

Comment: i'm trying to encrypt a string by adding a ascii to the original character for sample letter A = ASCII is 65 and by adding 50 to the ASCII, Letter A turn to letter s = ASCII 115, but when i tried to convert "e" = ASCII 101 convert to • = ASCII 150 and transfer it to a string. it just give me a null or blank space.

Comment: i didn't edit it..... i cant give a code on this one.... for some sort of reason... but iv'e gave a sample situation...

Comment: This is not encryption. At best, it's obfuscation.

Comment: i really dont know what term will i use -_-

Comment: What you really want is a Ceasar Cipher: http://www.simonsingh.net/The_Black_Chamber/caesar.html

Answer (score 1):

Extended ASCII is just ASCII with the 8 high bits set to different values.

The problem lies in the fact that no commission has ratified a standard for extended ASCII. There are a lot of variants out there and there's no way to tell what you are using.

Now C# uses UTF-16 encoding which will be different from whichever extended ASCII you are using.

You will have to find the matching Unicode character and display it as follows

```
string a ="\u2649"  ; //where 2649 is a the Unicode number
Console.write(a) ;
```

Alternatively you could find out which encoding your files use and use it like so 
eg. encoding Windows-1252:

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
```

and for UTF-16

```
Encoding enc = new UnicodeEncoding(false, true, true);
```

and convert it using

```
 Encoding.Convert (Encoding, Encoding, Byte[], Int32, Int32)
```

Details are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66sschk1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
Convert those charcaters as string as folows.

```
string equivalentLetter = Encoding.Default.GetString(new byte[] { (byte)letter });
```

Now, the equivalent letter contains the correct string.
I tried this for EURO symbol, it worked.

Comment: What you're doing is simply throwing a part of the original letter away (char != byte) and treating it with an unspecified encoding. (Encoding.Default is configuration dependent)

Comment: @Polity : I said that this is just a way and I rendered some extended ascii chars with this...This is just a solution or the above question.

Comment: No its not, there is no guarantee that your call will even work on the QA's machine since Encoding.Default is configuration dependent

Answer (score 0):

.NET strings are UTF-16 encoded, not extended-ascii (whatever that is). By simply adding a number to a character will give you another defined character within the UTF-16 plain set. If you want to see the underlying character as it would be in your extended ASCII encoding you need to convert the newly calculated letter from whatever encoding you are talking about to UTF-16. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66sschk1.aspx

Comment: "extended ascii" is basically any one-byte-per-character text encoding for which the 0-127 byte values have the same meaning as the pure ASCII ones. (though technically UTF-8, which has 1 byte per character for that byte range, can also be seen as extended ASCII) The term was misused/misunderstood by the asker.