# c# Hex string to ASCII conversion results in '?'

Tags: c#

i.e. the hex 'BF', while in conversion sites the ASCII equivalent is '¿' in my code this hex and any higher get '?' instead. how can i get the conversion to include these characters too?

```
BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory , "kek.txt") , FileMode.Create), Encoding.ASCII);

        binaryWriter.Write("\xBF");

        binaryWriter.Close();
```

Comment: utf-8 encoding maybe? Just an idea, NOT an answer, so keep the flaming low :-)

Comment: What is BF? It's outside ASCII (BF=277). So you need to understand what encoding do you use

Comment: @Shrike: BF = 11 * 16 + 15 = 191

Comment: Isn't there a canonical question yet that explains why Encoding.ASCII returns question marks? What did your research show? Why do you explicitly pass the ASCII encoding anyway?

Comment: @Shrike I'm struggling to see how a single byte value might ever be more than 255.

Comment: @PaulF you're right ) shame on me, it mixed  up DEC and OCT in calculator ))

Comment: @spender sure, no way )

Comment: was testing on the wrong file and the 8-bit encoding had done the trick

Comment: Why not `Encoding.Default`?

Comment: @i486 Encoding.Default is specifically designed to vary by OS, user, process, thread and time. Most use cases of encoding require using exactly one encoding for all time, all users, ….

Comment: @kw7 If you prefer exceptions rather then silent data corruption, use an Encoding like this: `Encoding.GetEncoding("US-ASCII", EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback, DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback)`

Comment: @TomBlodget I agree, but with `Encoding.Default` there is a chance to work - with `ASCII` will never have success with  '¿'. BTW, `Default` can be inappropriate for specific PC (system) - it is global and common for all users, processes and threads. Different OS (Windows) versions are also not a problem (since XP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think, that ASCII is able to use '¿'. Try UTF8 instead.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters

Answer (score 0):

You need to write byte values, rather than strings - try this :

```
BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory , "kek.txt") , FileMode.Create), Encoding.ASCII);
byte b = 0xBF;
binaryWriter.Write(b);
binaryWriter.Close();
```

For a bit more of an explanation of the "problem" see this link : [ASCII Extended in C# string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945004/ascii-extended-in-c-sharp-string)